# fzero or fsolve ? differents results - Who is the correct ?

Tags: matlab, precision

I have a function

```
b=2.02478;
g=3.45581;
s=0.6;
R=1;

p =@(r) 1 - (b./r).^2 - (g^-2)*((2/15)*(s/R)^9 *(1./(r - 1).^9 - 1./(r + 1).^9 - 9./(8*r).*(1./(r - 1).^8 - 1./(r + 1).^8)) -(s/R)^3 *(1./(r-1).^3 - 1./(r+1).^3 - 3./(2*r).*(1./(r-1).^2 - 1./(r+1).^2)));
options = optimset('Display','off');
tic
   r2 =  fzero(p,[1.001,100])
   toc
   tic
    r3 =  fsolve(p,[1.001,100],options)
  toc
```

and the answer

```
r2 =

    2.0198

Elapsed time is 0.002342 seconds.

r3 =

    2.1648    2.2745

Elapsed time is 0.048991 seconds.
```

which is more confiable ? fzero returns different values than fsolve

Comment: I don't understand your notation on your parameters, can you edit to clarify

Comment: the parameters b can be any number start at 0 and finish at 10. Example, b= 1.5 and g = 1 ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always look at the exit flag (or output struct) of a function, especially when your result is not as expected.

This is what I get:

- `fzero(func,[1.00001,100])`:

  ```
  X = 4.9969
  FVAL
  EXITFLAG = 1 % fzero found a zero X.
  OUTPUT.message = 'Zero found in the interval [1.00001, 100]'
  ```
- `fzero(func,1.1)`:

  ```
  X = 1
  FVAL = 8.2304e+136
  EXITFLAG = -5 % fzero may have converged to a singular point.
  OUTPUT.message = 'Current point x may be near a singular point. The interval [0.975549, 1.188] reduced to the requested tolerance and the function changes sign in the interval, but f(x) increased in magnitude as the interval reduced.'
  ```

The meaning of the exit flag is explained in the matlab documentation:

> ```
>  1 Function converged to a solution x.
> -5 Algorithm might have converged to a singular point.
> -6 fzero did not detect a sign change.
> ```

So, based on this information it is clear that the first one gives you the correct result.

**Why does `fzero` fails**

As [documented in the manual](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html), `fzero` calculates the zero by finding a sign change:

> tries to find a point `x` where `fun(x) = 0`. This solution is where `fun(x)` changes sign—fzero cannot find a root of a function such as `x^2`.

Therefore, `X = 1` is also a solution of your formulation as the sign changes at this location from +inf to -inf as can be seen on a plot:

[image]

Note that it is always a good idea to provide a search range if possible as mentioned in the manual:

> Calling `fzero` with a finite interval guarantees `fzero` will return a value near a point where `FUN` changes sign.
>
> **Tip:** Calling `fzero` with an interval (`x0` with two elements) is often faster than calling it with a scalar `x0`.

**Alternative: `fsolve`**

Note that this method is developed for solving a system of multiple nonlinear equations. Therefore, it is not as efficient as `fzero` (~20x slower in your case). `fzero` uses gradient based methods (check the [manual](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html?searchHighlight=fsolve&s_tid=doc_srchtitle#butbmfz-5) for more information), which may work better in certain situations, but may get stuck in a local extrema. In this case, the gradient of your function gives the correct direction as long as your initial value is larger than 1. So, for this specific function `fsolve` is somewhat more robust than `fzero` with a single initial value, i.e. `fsolve(func, 1.1)` returns the expected value.

**Conclusion:** In general, use `fzero` with a search range instead of an initial value if possible for a single variable and `fsolve` for multiple variables. If one method fails, you can try another method or another starting point.

Comment: can i use another thing ? fsolve, findroot , is it better than fzero ?

Comment: `fsolve` works too and somewhat more robust _for your case_ (see my edited answer). I don't know `findroot`.

Comment: Note that I only provided some general rules, for a full understanding you should dive into the underlying algorithms. The references of [`fsolve`](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html#References) and [`fzero`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html#References) may be a good starting point.

Comment: I edited my code and put all of it, my entire program and tell about my problem.  THe startint point of r_min change the value of I_value problem. If  you have time to do that, try to test and see what is wrong.

Comment: ah ok ...if you have time to see my code, i will aprecciate .. it is for my phd ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894347/starting-point-fzero-gives-differents-values-for-different-starting-points  my question - edited .. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in documentation:

> The algorithm, which was originated by T. Dekker, uses a combination of bisection, secant, and inverse quadratic interpolation methods.

So, it is sensitive into the initial point and area which it is seeking for the solution. Hence, you have gotten different result for different initial value and scope.

Comment: I edited my code and put all of it, my entire program and tell about my problem.  THe startint point of r_min change the value of I_value problem. If  you have time to do that, try to test and see what is wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894347/starting-point-fzero-gives-differents-values-for-different-starting-points  my question - edited .. thanks for your time